# Why can I have an innerHTML which counts up but not a dataset which counts up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this. The first item of the list is a number counting upwards.

```js
setInterval(randomNumber, 1000);

function randomNumber() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var el = document.getElementById('move');
    var currentScore = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
    el.innerHTML = currentScore+1;      
    $('.listitems li').sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
    }
    $('.listitems li').sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
            <li id="move" data-position="1">1</li>
            <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
            <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
            <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
            <li data-position="5">Item 5</li>
            <li data-position="6">Item 6</li>
            <li data-position="7">Item 7</li>
            <li data-position="8">Item 8</li>
            <li data-position="9">Item 9</li>
            <li data-position="10">Item 10</li>
        </ul>
```

Now what I want is for the first item to have a "data-position" attribute which counts upwards so it moves one place down the list every second, but I've tried the snippet below and it doesn't have the desired effect. What am I doing wrong?

```js
setInterval(randomNumber, 1000);

function randomNumber() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var el = document.getElementById('move');
    var currentScore = parseFloat(el.dataset.position);
    el.dataset.position = currentScore+1;      
    $('.listitems li').sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
    }
    $('.listitems li').sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
                <li id="move" data-position="1">1</li>
                <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
                <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
                <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
                <li data-position="5">Item 5</li>
                <li data-position="6">Item 6</li>
                <li data-position="7">Item 7</li>
                <li data-position="8">Item 8</li>
                <li data-position="9">Item 9</li>
                <li data-position="10">Item 10</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: It's because you're mixing jQuery and vanilla JS. Use `$('#move').data('position', $('#move').data('position')+1);` to set the data attribute.

Comment: thank you that worked for me